# Dynamically resize a symbol using AS3 and then apply tween on the resultant symbol

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am able to use a classic tween to move a symbol on the stage ( frame 2 to frame 15) on stage layer. I apply AS3 command to resize the symbol ( a simple rectangle  as movie) in frame 0 on AS3 layer. I issue stop() command at frame 15 on the AS3 layer. They work independently but the resultant resized symbol is not shown. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Combining motion (designed) tweens and programming will bring you a lot of grief and head ache. I advise you **not** to do it unless you absolutely must. Try programmed tweening, the downside of it is that you don't get to see the result design-time, the huge upside is how flexible and controllable it is: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/transitions/Tween.html

Comment: Thanks +1 . @Organis